# How to check posting username and password valid or not in url in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, get

I new to this field. I need to check are username and password valid.

What I tried is I have a local URL, username is `23` and password is `rama` so when I pass that name to URL, after hit that URL we show "username is valid" in browser.

But now I need to enter `username` and `password` in two `textFields` and then click on Submit button to show is it valid or not.

I followed [this link](http://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/) but no luck for me. Please give me any idea.

I tried like this without any luck:

```
username = @"23";
password = @"rama";
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@&password=%@",username, password];
NSLog(@"%@", postString);
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.3.196:8090/SaveDollar/rest/users/findByUser/userid/password"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do I get it right, that you are checking user name and password in some remote database? Or maybe let me rephrase it: Is response whether data entered is valid, comes from requested URL?

Comment: @Piotr YES comes with URL

Comment: So logic should be on the URL side. Use the guide you provided. On the URL side you will have access to POST as a table with two fields: Username and Password. Check if they match and return answer.

Comment: @Piotr please lock my code once

Comment: I am not ObjC programmer. I don't know if it's relevant, but you variable names don't match - username1, password1
And I am not sure where the problem is. Server or client side?

Comment: @pavan alapati ,here how can u declare without the response of url user is valid or not..? it's not possible without and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a class with `NSURLConnectionDelegate.`
2. Add this method:

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  
    {  
         [_data setLength:0];  
         NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
         NSInteger code = [httpResponse statusCode];
         if (code >= 200 && code <= 299 ) {
             NSLog(@"~~~~~ Request Maker Success! Code: %ld", (long)code);
         } else {
             NSLog(@"~~~~~ Request Maker Error! Code: %ld \n URL: %@", (long)code, _urlSent);
         }
    }
   ```
3. This is how you make a request with your name and password. You just make request and wait. `didReceiveResponce` will fire automatically. You can put this code into `viewDidLoad` or connect this to your button.

   ```
   NSString *someurl = @"http://%@:%@/rest?_name=%@&_pwd=%@";

   NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:someurl, @"address", @"port", @"username", @"password"];
   NSString *urlStringFixed = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStringFixed];
   NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
   NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [theRequest addValue: @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
   NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

   if (connection){
       // Connection exist
   }
   ```

**Update.**

You will need some web service. I tried your URL with `rama` and `23` but it's not responding.

Assuming, your service is working. In case password and name matching it will return code `200.` You can inspect code in browser web inspector. No need to parse web content from your page. Your Objective-C code will listen for any response from the server. If `code >= 200 and <= 299,` — everything all right.

Comment: thanks for Replay but username and password append to Url but Please tell me how to check valid user or not my web service Valid user and password it's return YES it's not valid it's return NO

Comment: @PavanAlapati I updated my answer. Don't hesitate to ask more question. Good luck.